# Python html format all select table row

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT [APPL_NAME] ,[JOB_NAME],[LABE] FROM XYZ)
         resultat = cursor.fetchall()
         for row in resultat:
                html_code = """
                 <!doctype html>
             <html>
             <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <title>Untitled Document</title>
             <body>
                 <table border='1'
                 <tr>
                     <th>Date</th>
                     <th>Count</th>
                     <th>Status</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     
                     <td>{}</td>
                     <td>{}</td>
                     <td>{}</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
                 </body>
                 </html>""".format(row[0],row[1],row[3])
```

I am trying to fetch the record from database table and send the data in email. In table for select query 10-20 record. But in email only one record printing in table with above code.
I tried to all the data in list but no luck. Please suggest me how to format the all select table records in email. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad algorithm. In the loop, you replace all the html code instead of adding a new line.

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT [APPL_NAME],[JOB_NAME],[LABE] FROM XYZ""")
resultat = cursor.fetchall()
```

Create rows:

```
rows_code = ""
for row in resultat:
    rows_code = rows_code + """
        <tr>
             <td>{}</td>
             <td>{}</td>
             <td>{}</td>
        </tr>
    """.format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

Create full html code:

```
html_code = """
    <!doctype html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     <body>
         <table border='1'
         <tr>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Count</th>
             <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
         {}
         </table>
         </body>
         </html>
""".format(rows_code)
```

Comment: ('row index out of range index=3 len=3',) Hi, thanks for the code. But I am facing index out of range issue. could you please suggest more